# Всегда ли alter table блокирует таблицу?

Tags: sql, oracle

Всегда ли alter table блокирует таблицу? Или есть какие-то исключения. Например, добавление поля и изменение его размера. Или дайте ссылку, где можно почитать об этом, не нашел.

Comment: Ответ зависит от Engine таблицы, конкретной выполняемой операции и точной версии сервера. Но минимальная блокировка существует всегда. Хотя бы потому, что необходимо исключить конкурентные интерферирующие ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Например, 19 версия, добавление поля или изменение его размерности. Какие блокировки будут накладываться в обоих случаях? И можете дать ссылку на какую-то документацию именно по блокировкам при alter table - хоть убей ничего не могу найти (((

Comment: Признаться, боюсь, что и не найдёте. Проприетарный продукт, internals считай отсутствуют..

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Пойду тогда тернистым путем экспериментов, проб и ошибок ))))